# How do I display dynamically filled span items separated by commas using JQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have these span elements that may or may not be filled dynamically at runtime. I need to display the span elements that are filled, with the text separated by commas. So for the HTML below, the output would look like this: 'Filled 1, Filled 2, Filled 3'.

```
   <div>   
        <h6>
            <span>Filled1</span>
            <span></span>
            <span>Filled 2</span>
            <span>Filled 3</span>
            <span></span>
        </h6>
   </div>
```

I tried to do this by selecting the non-empty span items and adding them to an array using JQuery, but it didnt seem to work. How can I do this? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Usually you get help faster if you show how much time you've already invested in finding a solution to the problem. How do you show that? The jQuery code you've written but doesn't work. Take this advice for next time when you want to ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easy with **jQuery**, try something like this:

**[This code was updated to replace the last comma for the 'and' word]**

```
$(function(){
  var texts = [];

  $('span').each(function(){
    if($(this).text()) texts.push($(this).text());
  });

  var result = texts.join(', ');
  var lastComma = result.lastIndexOf(',');

  result = result.substring(0, lastComma) + ' and' + result.substring(lastComma + 1);

  alert(result);
})
```

Look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/xbbXby).

*Just replace the `alert` for whatever you want to do with the results*

Comment: Thanks, this looks good! Also, is there any way I can add 'and' before the last filled span? So it would look like: 'Filled 1, Filled 2 and Filled 3'

Comment: @PrincessBelle I have updated the solution to fit your needs. Please accept the solution if it works or feel free to ask me whatever you want.

Comment: Your updated solution doesnt seem to work? The alert wont pop up

Comment: @PrincessBelle mmm I tested and is working as expected. Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/xbbXby

Answer (score 2):

Try this, pure css ##  Edited as the way I had it left a comma at the end if there was a empty last span ##

```css
span:not(:first-of-type):before {content:", ";}
span:empty:before{content:"";}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span>filled 1</span>
  <span>filled 2</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>filled 3</span>
  <span>filled 4</span>
  <span></span>
 </h3>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but it still adds a comma if the last span is empty. Is there a way to fix that? Thank you

Comment: oh, Sorry, didn't notice, I'll look into it now.

Comment: I think you're gonna have to go with JS/Jquery, by the time the css gets to the last empty span, it's too late and the damage is done. I'll look into it more tomorrow and let you know if I find a css only solution but it's 3.55 am here so I'm off to beddy byes. Night night my Princess

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help and sweet dreams! Let me know if you find a CSS only solution!

Comment: I like your solution but the comma position seems to stuff up sometimes, so I've chosen the JQuery solution as the answer. This is still great though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scan for empty nodes, and if it is not empty, add the comma

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('h6')[0].getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
  if (spans[i].innerHTML != '' && (i + 2) < (spans.length)) {
    spans[i].innerHTML += ', ';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h6>
        <span>Filled1</span>
        <span></span>
        <span>Filled 2</span>
        <span>Filled 3</span>
        <span></span>
    </h6>
</div>
```